# ¿Cómo obtener la lista de dispositivos Bluetooth emparejados en Android?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Necesito obtener la lista de dispositivos `Bluetooth` emparejados y obtener información de ellos, nombre visible, dirección mac, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener la lista de los dispositivos bluetooth emparejados, se obtiene de `getBondedDevices` del adaptador actual bluetooth `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter`

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevicesList = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

for(BluetoothDevice pairedDevice : pairedDevicesList) {
    Log.d(TAG, "pairedDevice.getName(): " + pairedDevice.getName());
    Log.d(TAG, "pairedDevice.getAddress(): " +  pairedDevice.getAddress());

}
```

Comment: me parece super interesante

Comment: **Esta es la respuesta correcta**, la mía es una variación! @Webserveis.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la lista de dispositivos bluetooth aparejados este es mi método:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    List<String> listDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(BluetoothDevice btd : pairedDevices){
       listDevices.add(btd.getName());
    }
```

`listDevices` es una lista que contendrá los nombres de dispositivos bluetooth aparejados.